# Why using cross-entropy for calculating the loss in Variational Autoencoder

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

I am learning the theory and the implementation of variational autoencoder by reading [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/tutorials/generative/cvae). 
In the documentation, it said optimize the following function: log{p(x|z)} + log{p(z)} - log{q(z|x)}. However, in the code, I am not able to understand why the implementation used cross-entropy to calculate log{p(x|z)}. Can someone please explain to me how cross-entropy is linked to log{p(x|z)}?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, this is not my major but. Typically we speak about KL-divergence when defining variational loss. Cross entropy is a summ of KL-divergence and entropy of one distribution. If the entropy of that distribution does not depend on model params (i.e. it was sampled) than we can use CE instead of KL to produce loss. And these guys just left lots of that story out because they are focused on providing a technical guide

Comment: Hi @y.selivonchyk, thanks for your answer. When you said "If the entropy of that distribution does not depend on model params (i.e. it was sampled) than we can use CE instead of KL to produce loss", is this because using CE, one can actually calculate the gradient and doing backpropagation?

Comment: Absolutely. CE produces numeric output that can be used as loss and can be minimized. If any of the arguments of CE depends on model params than minimizing that loss we can produce gradients for the parameters. Keep in mind, that it does not necessarily mean that result of such training would be meaningful: in case of VAE a few more losses must be added.